# Should we convert mixins to the class-based component definition syntax in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

After reading the plan for Vue 3, I noticed that the statement mixins will still be supported. However, Should I convert all of mixins components to class-based-components in case that Vue stops supporting mixins in the future?

mixins:

export default class MyComponent extends mixins(A, B, C) {
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class API that was originally planned for Vue 3 has been [dropped](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17#issuecomment-494242121) and replaced with the [composition API](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/). While mixins will still be supported, composition functions have a [number of advantages](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#logic-extraction-and-reuse), such as avoiding namespace clashing, making it clearer where properties come from, and playing friendlier with Typescript.

Once Vue 3 is released I would recommend not writing more mixins but using Composition Functions. It'll be up to you to consider whether you rewrite old mixins - it will depend on whether you think the benefits of composition functions outweigh the initial cost of rewriting old mixins.